# Any way to teach google about my website?

Tags: google-search, google-search-console

I was looking for getting Google Sitelinks for my website and was surprised to see that Google already has generated sitelinks for my website cloudchowk.com , but only when searched in google as "[cloud chowk](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=cloud+chowk&oq=cloud+chowk&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.595.2491.0.2831.11.9.0.0.0.0.641.1199.5-2.2.0...0.0...1c.SCgI-MPv3PM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=c5b485026ad230b6&biw=1920&bih=955)" instead of the original & actual "[cloudchowk](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=cloudchowk&oq=cloudchowk&gs_l=hp.3..0i10j0.1269.3074.0.3456.10.10.0.0.0.0.234.1862.0j8j2.10.0...0.0...1c.rabHXeHHcVc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=c5b485026ad230b6&biw=1920&bih=955)".

I guess its based on the user-behavior information that Google has. Or I may be wrong.
Is there anyway to teach Google or work on something from my side to get Google sitelinks when my site is searched as "cloudchowk" ?

FYI: cloudchowk.com is a wordpress site that is live since an year or less.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The act of managing how your site is indexed is called Search Engine Optization (SEO).  Google has published a PDF to guide folks through the process of optimizing a site: [Search Engine Optimization Starter Guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en/us/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf).

I would also look at this Google support article: [Google 101: How Google crawls, indexes and serves the web.](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=70897)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I would take a look and come back soon.